# Get the first image in a page with class foo

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the first image with specific class from page by php

```
<?php
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-501465_162-57471379-501465/first-picture-on-the-internet-turns-20/'));
$lst = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');

for ($i=0; $i<$lst->length; $i++) {
    $image = $lst->item($i);
    echo $image->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->value, '<br />';
}
?>
```

this code get all images from the page, i'm trying now to get the images with class "cnet-image" from [this page](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-501465_162-57471379-501465/first-picture-on-the-internet-turns-20/)

Comment: Some details? Maybe even some code? We are not psychic

Comment: @F4r-20 I'm trying to get the first avatar from post page like this page http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1399697 I want to get this image http://forums.digitalpoint.com/image.php?u=246759&dateline=1256890274

Comment: Is PHP used to generate the pages with the specified images?

Comment: @F4r-20 no i want to add specific page link like i use it with file_get_contents

Comment: @F4r-20 I got a code but need some help with the specific class image

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you need to with Simple HTML Dom, give it a try, I've used it for several similar things including image crawlers. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It looks like you should be able to use the following for what you need.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

$ret = $html->find('img[class=foo]');
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you want to retrieve the first image with a specific class attribute name in a HTML document.
If that's the case, then this could help.

```
var l = document.images;
var myclass = "myclass";//This is the class you want
var firstImageWithMyClass = null;

for(var i = 0; i<l; i++)
  if(document.images[i].className==myclass){
     firstImageWithMyClass = document.images[i];
     break;
   }

 //Then you can see if an image with that class was found, 
 //then do what you want to do withit here;
 if(firstImageWithMyClass!=null){
    var imageSource = firstImageWithMyClass.src;
    //etc, etc
 }
```

jQuery makes this easier. Let me know if you would like to know how to do the same with jQuery and I can share with you.

Comment: thank u but i need it with php to get the images from another page not the same page

Comment: Aha ok. I didn't have enough information from the question to be able to answer you. Perhaps you could try searching through your retrieved HTML string?