# Search and remove from result?

Tags: php

I got this result and i want extraction first image from folder clear just the first

Example of the result

```
http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/07/12/Les_Horribles_Cernettes_in_1992_620x350.jpg
http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/07/03/IBM-350-publicdomain_220x157.jpg
http://cbsdigitalmedia.112.2o7.net/b/ss/cbscbsnewscomatlantisuat/1/H.21--NS.png
http://dw.com.com/clear/c.gif
http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/07/03/IBM-350-publicdomain_220x157.jpg
http://dw.com.com/clear/test2.gif
http://cbsdigitalmedia.112.2o7.net/b/ss/cbscbsnewscomatlantisuat/1/H.21--NS.png
http://dw.com.com/clear/test.gif
```

The image i want

```
http://dw.com.com/clear/c.gif
```

Comment: How are the links stored? An Array? How do you know which of the links you are going to want?

Comment: @F4r-20 the result got it from this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266594/get-the-first-image-in-a-page-with-class-foo

Comment: Please explain Question we did not understand

Comment: I think I see now.. You would like to go through the array of image URLs and return the first one that comes within the `clear/` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I was actually quite intrigued by your question.. So I came up with a little something...

```
$firstFile;

//This is the array with your URL values
$imgUrls[0] = "http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/07/12/Les_Horribles_Cernettes_in_1992_620x350.jpg";
$imgUrls[1] = "http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/07/03/IBM-350-publicdomain_220x157.jpg";
$imgUrls[2] = "http://cbsdigitalmedia.112.2o7.net/b/ss/cbscbsnewscomatlantisuat/1/H.21--NS.png";
$imgUrls[3] = "http://dw.com.com/clear/c.gif";
$imgUrls[4] = "http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2012/07/03/IBM-350-publicdomain_220x157.jpg";
$imgUrls[5] = "http://dw.com.com/clear/test2.gif";
$imgUrls[6] = "http://cbsdigitalmedia.112.2o7.net/b/ss/cbscbsnewscomatlantisuat/1/H.21--NS.png";
$imgUrls[7] = "http://dw.com.com/clear/test.gif";

//This foreach loop goes through the array and checks the containing directory
foreach($imgUrls as $value){
    $urlParts = explode("/",$value);
    if($urlParts[count($urlParts)-2] == "clear"){
        $firstFile = $value;
        break;
    }
}

//After setting $firstFile as the Image URL, echo it out.
echo $firstFile;
```